# Why there's something called "Electric Field" where the force of two charges never turns to Zero with Infinite distance?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

[image]An **Electric Field** will be called a area where the *force* of a charge(or charged thing) actually work.The *force* should be lowest at the edge of the Electric Field. After That Zero. But Here I think the *force* never turn zero whatever the distance is, even infinity!

I targeted ***Proton*** . Charge **1.602 * 10<sup>-19</sup>**.

If I place another *Proton* at a distance of **10 * 10<sup>20</sup> m** then the *force* between them will be -

**F  =  Cqq/d<sup>2</sup>  =  2.31<sup>-70</sup>**

That means the electric field is **10 * 10<sup>20</sup>/2 = 5 * 10<sup>19</sup>+ m**  (Two *Protons*. Both have charge)

If distance is **20 * 10<sup>30</sup>** **m** then **F = 5.78 * 10<sup>-91</sup>** and *electric field* is **10 * 10 <sup>30</sup>+ m**

This Process just continues with larger distance(to infinity) but never the force turn at zero between them.

That means *there's* *no constant field for the energy?*

Then Why Called *Electric Field*? *Infinite Electric Field?*

In The Picture - The Force From 'A' Works For 'q' but not for 'q2'. but I think it should work!

Comment: A field is not generally regarded as a region where a thing is constant, but rather a region where a thing is defined. Thus in my apartment we would speak of the temperature field, meaning that every point has a defined temperature -- but it is nonzero everywhere within and varies from quite warm next to the oven and behind the fridge and by the dryer -- think all of the places a cat would like to hang out -- and cooler in the bathroom and in front of the air conditioner vents and anywhere else that the cool air collects. It's even noticeably warmer at the ceiling than the floor.

Comment: Can you rephrase this so that your usage of "field" aligns with the definition that I just gave you, so that we can have a clearer understanding of your problem?

Comment: Its an area where the force of a charge works. there's no force outside the field(area). Thats what I tried to mean

Comment: Okay, so if there's nothing about "constant" in the definition you're using for field, why are you so scandalized that the potential energy field for a point charge is not constant?

Comment: Actually I tried to mean, force from a charge from a corner from the universe should work to another corner of the universe. Infinite Distance. Then how can be there a constant area for the charge that we call Electric Field?

Comment: what does "constant area for the charge" mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is a physics discussion site, thus the vocabulary is not optional but should obey the conventions and mathematical models of present day physics, as represented in textbooks and peer reviewed articles.

Here is the definition of a field for physics :

> [In physics, a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)) is a physical quantity, represented by a number or tensor, that has a value for each point in space and time. For example, on a weather map, the surface wind velocity is described by assigning a vector to each point on a map. Each vector represents the speed and direction of the movement of air at that point. As another example, an electric field can be thought of as a ["condition in space"](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_04.html) emanating from an electric charge and extending throughout the whole of space. When a test electric charge is placed in this electric field, the particle accelerates due to a force.

The force is mathematically modeled.

Mathematics has no restrictions in space and time, thus regions in space can be described mathematically where the models can never be tested by a physics experiment, due to the very small values of the variables. This does not invalidate the concept, it just makes the extrapolation to such distances physically irrelevant.

> The force should be lowest at the edge of the Electric Field. After That Zero.

If you look at the mathematical model of the electric field, there is no mathematical zero. Physical zero occurs when the values calculated from the model  are smaller than measurement error.